# PhoneGap Build Android Audio Not Working

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap Build to launch an Android application. My html and everything works perfectly in the browser. However, it does not on my Android device. Does it have something to do with the permissions? I'm really not sure, and am completely confused as to where to go next. Below I have my html and javascript.

I do not have a context file, fyi. My folders are css, img, js, and sound.

Let me know if you can help!

html + javascript

```
<h1 id= "main">GO</h1>

var pp = 1;
            var audio = new Audio('sound/sound1.mp3');
$("#main").click(function(){
                console.log(pp);
                if (pp == 1){
                    audio.play();
                    pp++;
                    console.log(pp);
                }else if (pp == 2){
                    audio.pause();
                    pp--;
                    console.log("audio pause");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a permission issue, rather, your HTML/Javascript code 
is run/loaded inside a customized Android Webview (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

This Webview does have several quirks and does not quite behave, like
a browser would in some cases.

One of those cases is playing audio or video. On Android, there is 
MediaPlayer to do that. If you were running this code in a 'normal'
Android application you would have an Activity that contains an 
instance of WebView. To play media files you could for example 
inject an object http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
that plays the audio or video using Android's MediaPlayer.

So basically, it just doesn't work the way, you try, right now.
However Phonegap provides an API to work around this issue.
Possible that they are doing, what I just explained above.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html